# Issue when deleting a nested model with minimum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a model named Project which has many Tasks. Every Project needs to have at least one Task.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  validates :tasks, length: {minimum: 1}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, allow_destroy: true
end

class Descripcion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, 
        :tasks_attributes => [:id, :content, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

The validation works when I'm trying to register a new Project, but if I'm editing an existing one and remove every task from it, the validation doesn't occur and it's saved without the tasks.
I found the issue when running this test:

```
test "should not destroy tasks" do
  tasks = []
  @project.tasks.each do |t|
    tasks<< {id: t.id, _destroy: true}
  end

  assert_no_difference('Task.count') do
    patch :update, id: @project, project: { tasks_attributes: tasks}
  end
  assert_template :edit

end
```

I'm using rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain why your `validates :tasks` isn't running when saving the Project instances.  But if you are saving the Tasks via the Project via nested attributes... then something like this should work

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, allow_destroy: true
  validate :must_have_tasks

  private
    def must_have_tasks
      errors.add(:tasks, "Project needs to have at least one task") if tasks.all? { |task| task.marked_for_destruction? }
    end
end
```

If you are saving the Task instance independent from the Project parent, you can check add something like,

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :not_only_task?
  belongs_to :project

  private
  def not_only_task?
    project.tasks.length > 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about the marked_for_destruction? attribute. I will try it when I get home and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Thanks! Now it works as expected. I'd like why the standard validation didn't work, though...